# PHPMailer - How to disable SMTPDebug?

Tags: php

It seems that PHPMailer logs.

I tried deleting the following line:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Instead of deleting the line, use  $phpmailer->SMTPDebug=0;

Comment: You should always start by [reading the manual](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/SMTP-Debugging). It's pretty straight forward: _SMTP::DEBUG_OFF (0): Disable debugging (you can also leave this out completely, 0 is the default)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this line of code:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
```

Comment: In my opinion, we shouldn't answer where the OP clearly are using Stack Overflow instead of doing their own research, seeing that what they are asking about is not just very well documented, they would def. have found the answer pretty fast if they just googled it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Especially when it's two accounts just answering and upvoting each other's questions

Comment: @iainn - Ah, one of those...

Answer (score 2):

`$mail->SMTPDebug = 0; //set smtpdebig to 0`